# How does the cantrip Infestation interact with immunity to poison?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, immunities

I really like this spell for my Druid and I was wondering if the non-damage effect of the spell would still take place, even if a creature has immunity to Poison fails its saving throw?

> The target must succeed on a Constitution saving throw, or it takes 1d6 poison damage and moves 5 feet in a random direction if it can move and its speed is at least 5 feet. Roll a d4 for the direction: 1., north; 2, south; 3, east; or 4, west. This movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks, and if the direction rolled is blocked, the target doesn't move.
>   (XGtE p.158)

Obviously the damage would be zero, but would the affected creature still have to make a Saving Throw and, on a fail, cause it to move in a "random direction"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### They are still moved

In this spell, it says that the effect of a failed constitution save is **both** damage and being moved. As you are immune to the damage, the damage acts as if it dealt 0 damage. As the ability never specified that immunity to poison prevent this movement, it would still happen as normal.

Comment: Would be good to mention how to rp it, the fleas and bugs are also an annoying swarming distraction up in ya face, just because the bites don’t damage dont mean they not up in ya grill.

Comment: Exactly why you'd still get moved. It would likely literally be a matter of backing up while trying to get the bugs out of your face

Comment: It's not an official ruling, but one of Crawford's tweets does agree with this answer: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/944015596592578560